# Sorting with special characters and space in the string

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am creating project using angular and material. In my project i am implementing sorting into the mat table. In the mat table data contains special characters and spaces, due to this sorting not working properly.

Example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-an1uqc-zkphvo?file=app%2Ftable-sorting-example.ts,app%2Ftable-sorting-example.html

```
sortData(sort: Sort) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(sort));

    const data = ELEMENT_DATA.slice();
    if (!sort.active || sort.direction === '') {
      this.sortedData = data;
      return;
    }

    const isAsc = sort.direction === 'asc';

    this.sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => {
      switch (sort.active) {
        case 'position':
          return compareNumber(a.position, b.position, isAsc);
        case 'name':
          return compareString(a.name, b.name, isAsc);
        case 'description':
          return a.description.localeCompare(b.description) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
        default:
          return 0;
      }
    });
  }

function compareString(a: string, b: string, isAsc: boolean) {
  return (
    a.replace(/^[^a-z]+/i, 'z').localeCompare(b.replace(/^[^a-z]+/i, 'z')) *
    (isAsc ? 1 : -1)
  );
}
```

Expectation : Order should be special charcters items should be end in the list while asceding and desecending

Comment: Please define  "...not working properly"

Comment: What should be the order?

Comment: Your question seems unrelated to angular and material, but just to sorting of an array of strings. Please provide sample input and expected output inside your question. You can also include a runnable snippet so that we can actually run your code (again, no Angular is needed to sort an array).

Comment: @trincot Example alredy added and expected output also

Comment: I don't see any example in your question, nor expected output for that example.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-an1uqc-zkphvo?file=app%2Ftable-sorting-example.ts,app%2Ftable-sorting-example.html 
Expectation : Order should be special charcters items should be end in the list while asceding and desecendin @trincot

Comment: Not behind a link. Links can break. Please edit your question and add a concrete example inside your question, and include the expected result for the input. Instead of *"not working properly"*, be explicit in what you get and how that differs from the output you expect.

Comment: I would create a separate field of data that strips out all special characters, and then sort on that field.